# File upload to dotnetcore api not working with a kestrel socketexception

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have dotnetcore 2.2.2 web api application that is being hosted on IIS.  There is an angular client that is used to interact with this api.

Very intermittently we are having issues with file uploads not working, and strangely I haven't been able to replicate it on my pc but can on 2 others.  The error in our logs is.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessReceives()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
```

I can't track down to what might cause this but am wondering if there is a bug within kestrel itself that could be causing this?

Some configuration includes:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)     
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);                        
                        options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 80, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                        options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 80, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                    })
                   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                   {
                       // delete all default configuration providers
                       config.Sources.Clear();
                       config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                       config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                   }).Build();
```

I'm not sure what else to provide as info as nothing seems to be logged as far as the request getting into the controller itself.  But the controller receiving the request takes a `Stream` as it's media parameter.  So in this case I'm not using an IFormFile but instead the code to receive is based from [microsofts site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Looks familiar: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4733

Comment: @TimothyJohnLaird yes possibly similiar.  Unfortunately I don't see an answer there.  Also I'm pretty sure this only started happening on upgrade to 2.2.2.  I didn't see it much on 2.2.1.. I'm hoping to maybe upgrade to 2.2.3 but not holding my breath this will fix anything.

Comment: Hmm true. You mention that you are using IIS...which would seem to indicate that you are doing a reverse proxy. I think that might be adding a wrinkle because the socket error you are getting could indicate that IIS is giving up and dropping the socket to kestrel after not sending all the bytes for the file. And kestrel could be justifiably freaking out when it doesn't get all the bytes it expects. So...could you take IIS out of the equation and see if the errors manifest with you just hitting Kestrel?

Comment: So I tried making my IIS app pool to a managed pool which I believe stops it from acting as a reverse proxy however the problem is still happening.  Annoying thing is I can easily replicate it on 2 pcs but can't on 3 others...

Comment: sorry that was to no managed.. But still happening.